# Expresion regular que no separe frases entre comillas en C#

Tags: c#, regex

Necesito crear un expresión regular para un analizador léxico que obtenga el texto entre comillas dobles pero que incluya las comillas.

Ejemplo:

```
"Hola mundo"
```

Mi código es el siguiente, pero no funciona:

```
lexico.AddReglaToken(@"/\"[^"]* "|'[^']*'/", "IDENTIFICADOR");
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con la regex `\".*\"`